# Using "&&" is not effective for cURL submit form (don't execute second line if first line fails)

Tags: command-line, curl

I'm submitting to my website using cURL. I make cURL post it in timely fashion.

In below code; first line is curl submit; second line is for queuing:

```
curl -b cookies.txt \
    -d title="$(sed '1,/sblmtitle/d;/slpstitle/,$d' sedut.html)" \
    -d taxonomy%5Btags%5D%5B1%5D="$(
        sed '1,/sblmkategori/d;/slpskategori/,$d' sedut.html
    )" \
    -d teaser_include=1 \
    -d body="$(sed '1,/sblmkonten/d;/slpskonten/,$d' sedut.html)" \
    -d field_source%5B0%5D%5Burl%5D="$(
        sed '1,/sblmurl/d;/slpsurl/,$d' sedut.html
    )" \
    -d changed= \
    -d form_build_id=form-424f851ad50bd4781c8c25ab7efd5c4c \
    -d form_token=0e7cc7437faf816f1ecd96087286bda9 \
    -d form_id=post_node_form \
    -d op=Save http://www.web.org/submit/post &&
for file in $(ls *.html | sort -r | tail -1); do
    mv $file sedut.html
done
```

If cURL fails to submit, it will print out `sedut.html` contents. If cURL success submitting, it will print nothing. In my case, sometime cURL fails to submit.

What I want is don't execute second line if first line fails. But using `&&` as above codes is just not works. I've tested it, cURL submit fails and print out `sedut.html` contents, but second line still executed.

Comment: Have you checked the `curl` exit status? Is it different in your fail and not-fail situations?

Comment: enzotib@ It giving me `0` even on failed submission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curl` has no idea that it failed - it had well-defined input, it communicated with the server and got back a `200 OK` response. Because of this, you can't rely on the exit code of `curl` (which is what `&&` does).

Instead, we have to use something else to determine success or failure, such as the output generated by `curl`.

As a side note, it is generally not a good idea to use `ls` in a script. Here, it will fail if a file happens to have a newline or a space character. It may be unlikely, but but it's possible. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for more details. As a rule of thumb, I only use `ls` in scripts when displaying the results for human eyes. If I'm processing the results in any way, I use `find . -0 ...`

Answer (score 1):

`&&` and `||` (as a success/fail tests) must be on the same logical line as the command(s) you want to be executed.  Use a line continuation  `&& \`  and/or curly brackets `{  }`

*Note:* As pointed out by *amphetamachine*, the line continuation issue does not apply in modern sh-compatible shells

```
true && echo "true"

true && \
   echo "true"

true && \
{  echo "true"; echo "===="; }

(( 123 == 123 )) && {
   echo "true"
   echo "====" 
}
```

Comment: In modern sh-compatible shells, `&&` and `||` don't need a backslash at the end as they are considered statement-ending marks like `;` and `&`. Shell code in makefiles can't do this, however.

Comment: @amphetamachine: Yes, I just tested it and it's true. thanks... How about that! That makes things a bit easier for general scripting, but it makes my answer somewhat useless for the question :(... but because it does work, that seems to imply that curl is returning a non-zero exit code