# Success/fail tests for cURL (don't execute second line if first line fails)

Tags: command-line, curl, testing

According to
[Using "&&" is not effective for cURL submit form (don't execute second line if first line fails)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22067/using-is-not-effective-for-curl-submit-form-dont-execute-second-line-if-fi)

In below code; first line is curl submit; second line is for queuing:

```
curl -b cookies.txt \
    -d title="$(sed '1,/sblmtitle/d;/slpstitle/,$d' sedut.html)" \
    -d taxonomy%5Btags%5D%5B1%5D="$(
        sed '1,/sblmkategori/d;/slpskategori/,$d' sedut.html
    )" \
    -d teaser_include=1 \
    -d body="$(sed '1,/sblmkonten/d;/slpskonten/,$d' sedut.html)" \
    -d field_source%5B0%5D%5Burl%5D="$(
        sed '1,/sblmurl/d;/slpsurl/,$d' sedut.html
    )" \
    -d changed= \
    -d form_build_id=form-424f851ad50bd4781c8c25ab7efd5c4c \
    -d form_token=0e7cc7437faf816f1ecd96087286bda9 \
    -d form_id=post_node_form \
    -d op=Save http://www.web.org/submit/post &&
for file in $(ls *.html | sort -r | tail -1); do
    mv $file sedut.html
done
```

If `cURL` fails to submit, it will print out `sedut.html` contents. If `cURL` success submitting, it will print nothing.

But `cURL` always giving `0` no matter if it success or failed in submitting.

I think the best workflow is "If `cURL` print nothing, run second line" and "If `cURL` print something, don't run second line"

I've just looked linux `if` command but still have no idea how to implement this because the example have different case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you hit upon the key here, if curl's output is different then you can test for it.  First you can direct that to a file.  Next you can leverage the -s option from test:

> -s file       True if file exists and has a size greater than zero.

Here is some example code:

```
curl -b cookies.txt ... -o /tmp/curl_output
if [ -s /tmp/curl_output ]; then
  do failure stuff here
else
  do successful stuff here
fi
```

Another implementation for academic reasons:

```
if curl -b cookies.txt ... 2>&1 | grep 'some line from sedut.html' >/dev/null 2>&1; then 
  do failure stuff here
else
  do successful stuff here
fi
```